# How Vertica handles semi-structured data even if loaded from different file formats

Tags: vertica

My understanding about semi-structured data handling in `Vertica` is that if data is say like this (in `json`)

```
{
"f1":1,
"f2":"hello",
"f3":false,
"f4":2
}
```

then a `flextable` is created with two columns `__identity__` and `__raw__`. `__identify__` will have 4 fields (I suppose integers 1,2,3,4) and `__raw__` will be raw representation of data (1, hello,false and 2).

I can also load data in a `csv` file in the same flextable eg `2, hello2, true, 3`. How does `Vertica` decide which field maps to which column (eg. both `f1` and `f4`) are `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing beats having a Vertica SQL prompt ready (and the privilege to create a database object ...) to try and find out.

With JSON, the field names are in the structure: key-value pairs.

With CSV, the first line of the data file needs to have the column names - which I add below ...

```
-- connecting with VSQL, 
$ vsql -h localhost -d sbx -U dbadmin -w pwd
$ vsql -h localhost -d sbx -U dbadmin -w pwd
Welcome to vsql, the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal.

Type:  \h or \? for help with vsql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

sbx=> -- create the flex table
sbx=> CREATE FLEX TABLE flx();
CREATE TABLE
sbx=> -- load the flex table from stdin - data handed in-line - using your input
sbx=> COPY flx FROM stdin PARSER fjsonparser();
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> {                                        
>> "f1":1,
>> "f2":"hello",
>> "f3":false,
>> "f4":2
>> }
>> \.
-- test the load ...
sbx=> SELECT f1,f2,f3,f4 FROM flx;
 f1 |  f2   |  f3   | f4 
----+-------+-------+----
 1  | hello | false | 2
sbx=>-- load the CSV file - note that we need the title line, 
sbx=>-- which I add, to have same values in the same fields
sbx=> COPY flx FROM stdin PARSER fcsvparser();
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> f1,f2,f3,f4
>> 2, hello2, true, 3
>> \.
sbx=>-- check the contents now
sbx=> SELECT f1,f2,f3,f4 FROM flx;
 f1 |   f2   |  f3   | f4 
----+--------+-------+----
 1  | hello  | false | 2
 2  | hello2 | true  | 3
sbx=>-- resulting table definition in catalog ...
sbx=> \d flx
                                             List of Fields by Tables
 Schema  | Table |    Column    |          Type          |  Size  | Default | Not Null | Primary Key | Foreign Key 
---------+-------+--------------+------------------------+--------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------
 dbadmin | flx   | __identity__ | int                    |      8 |         | t        | f           | 
 dbadmin | flx   | __raw__      | long varbinary(130000) | 130000 |         | t        | f           | 
(2 rows)

sbx=> -- check the contents of __identity__ and (after visualising) __raw__
sbx=> SELECT __identity__,REPLACE(MAPTOSTRING(__raw__),CHR(10),' ') FROM flx;
 __identity__ |                                REPLACE                                 
--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1 | {     "f1": "1",     "f2": "hello",     "f3": "false",     "f4": "2" }
            2 | {     "f1": "2",     "f2": "hello2",     "f3": "true",     "f4": "3" }
```

Comment: got it. So the `csv` file need the field names in the 1st line. I must have missed this detail.